# Javascript array id display sequence

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, sequence, getelementbyid

I've made a simple javascript array of prices that I want to use all around my website via ID attributes.

```js
var taxrate = 1.21

sp([
1.39, // size 1
1.11, // size 2
2.08, // size 3
2.09, // size 4
1.22 // size 5
]);

function sp(price) {
 
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < price.length; i++) {
    var id = "sp" + (i + 1);
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = price[i];
 
 var idtax = "sp" + (i + 1) + "tax";
 
 var subtotal = (price[i] * taxrate)
 
 var total = Math.round(subtotal*100)/100;
 
 document.getElementById(idtax).innerHTML = total;
  }
  }
```

```html
<span id="sp1"></span> <!-- size 1 -->
<span id="sp1tax"></span>
<span id="sp2"></span> <!-- size 2 -->
<span id="sp2tax"></span>
<span id="sp5"></span> <!-- size 5 -->
<span id="sp5tax"></span>
```

The problem is my webpage doesn't display values for the "size 5". I've tried to change the third span id to the "size 3" and then I get the values. If I change it back to "size 5" or "size 4", the values don't show again. If I begin with the "size 5" at the top of the list on my webpage, it get no values displayed at all. How can I display prices on my webpage using span tags in any possible ID sequence?

Comment: When something doesn't work as expected we need to figure out how to isolate and identify the problem. The first thing you should do is make sure your selectors are working.
```js
var span = document.getElementById(id);
console.log("span:", span);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a simple if condition to check whether the element with Id is found in document or not, and based on that process further

```js
var taxrate = 1.21

sp([
  1.39, // size 1
  1.11, // size 2
  2.08, // size 3
  2.09, // size 4
  1.22 // size 5
]);

function sp(price) {
  for (let i = 0; i < price.length; i++) {
    var id = "sp" + (i + 1);
    let elementId = document.getElementById(id)
    let idtax = "sp" + (i + 1) + "tax";
    let elementTaxId = document.getElementById(idtax)
    if (elementId && elementTaxId) {
      elementId.innerHTML = price[i];

      var subtotal = (price[i] * taxrate)

      var total = Math.round(subtotal * 100) / 100;

      elementTaxId.innerHTML = total;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<span id="sp1"></span>
<!-- size 1 -->
<span id="sp1tax"></span>
<span id="sp2"></span>
<!-- size 2 -->
<span id="sp2tax"></span>
<span id="sp5"></span>
<!-- size 5 -->
<span id="sp5tax"></span>
```

Comment: Brilliant! It works flawless now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

You need to check if the span with the id exists in the DOM and then apply the innerHTML to it.

```js
var taxrate = 1.21

sp([
1.39, // size 1
1.11, // size 2
2.08, // size 3
2.09, // size 4
1.22 // size 5
]);

function sp(price) {
 
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < price.length; i++) {
    var id = "sp" + (i + 1);
    let span = document.getElementById(id); // store the element reference in a variable
    if(span) { // check if element with id exists in DOM
       span.innerHTML = price[i]; // set the html using the variable
 
       var idtax = "sp" + (i + 1) + "tax";

       var subtotal = (price[i] * taxrate)
 
       var total = Math.round(subtotal*100)/100;
 
       document.getElementById(idtax).innerHTML = total;
      }
  }
}
```

```html
<span id="sp1"></span> <!-- size 1 -->
<span id="sp1tax"></span>
<span id="sp2"></span> <!-- size 2 -->
<span id="sp2tax"></span>
<span id="sp5"></span> <!-- size 5 -->
<span id="sp5tax"></span>
```

Comment: You're missing a closing paren on the if statement. Also you should store the selection as a variable to avoid running it twice (it's relatively expensive).

Answer (score 0):

```js
var taxrate = 1.21

sp([
  1.39, // size 1
  1.11, // size 2
  2.08, // size 3
  2.09, // size 4
  1.22 // size 5
]);

function sp(price) {
 
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < price.length; i++) {

    var id = "sp" + (i + 1);

    var span = document.getElementById(id);
    console.log("span "+id, span);

    if(span) { // check if element with id exists in DOM
      span.textContent = price[i];

      var taxSpan = document.getElementById(id + "tax");
      console.log("taxSpan "+id, taxSpan);

      if(taxSpan) {
        var subtotal = (price[i] * taxrate);
        var total = Math.round(subtotal*100)/100;
        taxSpan.textContent = total;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<span id="sp1"></span> <!-- size 1 -->
<span id="sp1tax"></span>
<span id="sp2"></span> <!-- size 2 -->
<span id="sp2tax"></span>
<span id="sp5"></span> <!-- size 5 -->
<span id="sp5tax"></span>
```